# What is the scientific term/keyword for "big data time series"?

Tags: bigdata, time-series, terminology

There are business articles from 2014 and 2015 that the time series analysis of the big data is the next big thing. However Google returns almost no scientific articles under the query "big data time series". I am sure the the research happens in this direction but **what terms should I use to find this research?** Big Dependent data? Large time series? Temporal big data? Streaming big data?

Comment: There are much work under the keyword "time series data mining" and "time series data mining algorithms"

Comment: "Almost no"? What was your search query? Searching google scholar for "time series big data" finds plenty of things to get your teeth into: https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=time+series+big+data&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=

Comment: Not all big data is amenable to time series analysis. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to do my thesis in computer science and it required theme about big data. The problem was, that time series analysis is mathematical discipline and I wanted to research the dynamical patterns in big data specifically - to convert it into computer science theme. That was history, I decided to work on theme about cognitive architectures. In future cognitive architectures will process big data and time series without human intervention.

Comment: One of four Vs (Volume, Variety, Velocity, Veracity) of big data is directly related to time series - it is Velocity.

Comment: You can always define your own term X and say: "In this paper/thesis I will use term X for such and such thing."

Comment: I liked "high speed data flows", but I guess it is not used a lot.